# Is there a mathematical basis behind the HSAB theory?

Tags: theoretical-chemistry, hsab

I learnt about the HSAB concept about a year ago, and found that it helped rationalise many of the solubilities/reactivities that “pure” Lewis acid/base theory could not.

Is there a mathematical basis behind Pearson’s theory, or was it just an empirical observation?

Comment: Be warned, HSAB theory can be deeply flawed: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/anie.201007100

Comment: Why do you have to start every question with 'Title.'? I have already asked you not to do that.